# Grouping different column into one row

Tags: mysql, group-by, grouping

How to make one row in different rows and column

```
SELECT  
    internal_id, store_id, user_id, shift_info,
    DATE(log_datetime) dates,   
    (case when log_action = '0' then TIME(log_datetime) end) as time_in,
    (case when log_action = '0' then CONCAT(log_lat, ",", log_lng) end) as loc_in,  
    (case when log_action = '1' then TIME(log_datetime) end) as time_out,   
    (case when log_action = '1' then CONCAT(log_lat, ",", log_lng) end) as loc_out 
FROM
    attendance_store_user   
WHERE 
    user_id = "A4CBD64F-D21C-5612-CCF5-497892B62E76"
```

[image]

i want result like this :

[image]

Comment: On what basics did you select Internal Id starting with `71..` to you expected output instead of all other internal ids?

Comment: internal id is unique, you can remove without internalid

Comment: Here's the thing, now you can see there are many internal_ids for the same store_ids right. In the expected output image you have chose the internal id starting with 71. Now how the system knows which to select and which to ignore. That's why I want to know how you select the id starting with 71 as the expected Internal_id. Meaning whats the reason behind choosing this number. This is one reason why in grouping we use aggregated function. Here for the Internal_id you'll have to use a aggregated function to use group by.

Answer (score 1):

You could  try using a join of the same table filter for null time_out and time_in

```
select  a.dates, a.store_id,  a,time_in, b.time_out 
FROM attendance_store_user a 
INNER JOIN attendance_store_user b on a.dates = b.dates 
  and a.user_id = b.user_id 
    and a.time_out is null 
      and b.time_in is null
WHERE a.user_id = "A4CBD64F-D21C-5612-CCF5-497892B62E76"
```